# Available arguments for docker commands

Tags: docker

When operating whith docker commands, I often struggle to find out the available arguments a command would take. For instance, when creating a volume:

```
docker volume create -d local -o ...
```

I can't find help anywhere in the command line and the on-line documentation I've found is based on "example" so no way to know if those are limited or extensive. Inspecting an already created volume may give some clues but that's not the solution.

Is there any way to see this info?

Comment: are you looking for this. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options

Comment: `docker volume COMMAND --help` this could help you.
Otherwise this has all you need: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/

Comment: Those links are the ones I refer to as "based on examples". They look quite incomplete. The "--help" is not that helpfull when it comes to avaialble options for commands like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CLI you have all the information you need.

You can use `--help` for any level. For example:

`docker --help` shows information about all the possible commands and what they do.

`docker volume --help` shows information about all the possible commands for the `volume` command.

`docker volume create --help` shows information about all the possible options for the `volume create` command.

And so on for any command.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just tells that using "-o" you can pass arguments, but I can't find anywhere a coprehensive list of such arguments.

Comment: @SebastiánGreco the information is right there, you just failed to read it. `Set driver specific options (default map[])`.  Now you need to decide which driver are you going to use (https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/), and look for information about this driver. So, e.g., if you decide for `btrfs`, look for information about the `btrfs`  (no related to docker, but to the file system itself), https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)